# TeamCity trunk build is triggered by commit in a branch

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity setup with two projects building different svn branches from the same repository.
First project is for the trunk (stable), and other is for my development branch.
Whenever I commit something to my branch, trunk build is triggered.

Is that normal and can it be avoided?

I'm using TeamCity 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marco, are you absolutely sure that your VCS settings for the trunk project do not include sources from the branch?

You configuration should be something like:

svn://server/root  (VCS root)

trunk => .   (checkout rules for trunk build)
branch/dev => . (checkout rules for branch build)

In this case, everything should work as expected.

Another thing - if your trunk and branch reference the same SVN external, and there is a change in this external, both builds will be triggered.

Comment: An external that is causing this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your trigger, e.g. the trigger pattern! Or you can write a custom build trigger :-).

Pattern for the trigger pattern :

```
+|-:[user][VCS root][path]
```